# why am i getting "error 404 headobject operation not found" while trying to copy files from one s3 bucket to another using lambda function?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to copy files from source s3 bucket to destination bucket using lambda function. S3 event notification will trigger the lambda function on any object creation event in source s3 bucket.
attached lambda code below (https://i.stack.imgur.com/st4Ff.png)

The file is successfully getting copied to the destination when I upload very small files of below 10kb. But when I upload actual file I am getting " An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Not Found" in cloudwatch logs.
I have given s3 full access and cloudwatch logs permission to lambda. The function gets the source bucket name , key and destination name successfully every time.
Why is it getting failed when i upload files greater than say 10kb?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)